# Change /var/www/html/ to /var/www/ because of 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: nginx, configuration, vagrant

I've ran into an issue with an upgrade on php version in Vagrant. That is solved but my problem now is that what was working before isn't now and has to do with the directory where the local projects are – I presume.

I have the local projects (as before) in `/var/www/` all the `*.conf` files in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` are the same and pointing to the `/var/www/`.

The `/etc/hosts` file remains as before pointing, for instance `192.168.56.102 awesome.devel`. This was working but not any more.

If I hit `192.168.56.102` on the browser it shoes me the **Congratulations! You are pretty awesome.** page which is located in `/var/www/html/`

**My question is**, where and how can I configure the server back to load the projects from **`/var/www/`** and not from `/var/www/html/` again, because it's there were all the projects are and all the `*.conf` files in `sites-available` and `sites-enabled` are configured.

Quick note: MariaDB is running fine, I can access the databases from Sequel Pro, I can ssh into vagrant, php running fine with `PHP 7.1.17-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1` no problems here.

In my .conf files I have the following (just changes the project name):

```
server {
    listen *:80;

    server_name awesome.devel www.awesome.devel;
    client_max_body_size 1m;

    root /var/www/awesome/public/;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/nxv_awesome.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/nxv_awesome.error.log;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # static file 404's aren't logged and expires header is set to maximum age
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: can you share one of the .conf file where the `root` directive is defined

Comment: Just added to the question the example of one .conf file

Comment: can you try in you browser `awesome.devel` . Because when you use the IP, nginx is rendering the default_server which is located in `/var/www/html` which can be seen in the file /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

Comment: That's when the problem happens - it gives me the 502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.8.0

Comment: Ah ok, so you have upgraded php version, and I believe you upgraded it to php7. Is php-fpm running on unix socket or tcp ? Please check the www.conf file for php7 for this. In this file check what is the entry for `listen` directive.

Comment: `listen = /run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock` that's what's there

Comment: ok then it wont work, as nginx is trying to connect to the tcp port and not the unix socket. Change it to `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000` and restart fpm. then it will work.

Comment: Hey tux, thanks so much! I'm really grateful - it's working now thanks to your help. Again, thank you very much! Can you place that last comment as an answer to my question so that I can credit you? :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the upgrade of php version, the config file for php has changed. The old php-fpm (version 5) was listening over tcp, but after upgrade php-fpm (version 7) is listening on the unix socket.

But according to the nginx configuration given above, nginx is trying to connect to php-fpm over tcp, but php7 is configured to listen on unix socket.

Changing the php config to listen over tcp will resolve the issue. The config in www.conf of php7 for the listen directive should be changed to the following

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```